# R - Upsert on a dataframe

Tags: r

I am working in R. I have 4 data frames with data I am attempting to summarize into a new dataframe. Basically the 4 starting frames have rownames that are unique identifiers (the rest have data about the identifier). There is potential for overlap, i.e. an ID might show up in more than one of the four tables.

I am attempting to build a dataframe with the following format:

```
ID-DATASET1-DATASET2-DATASET3-DATASET4
"1"-FALSE-FALSE-TRUE-TRUE
```

Basically this says that ID 1 appeared in datasets 3 and 4. So the goal is to come up with a boolean vector for each ID, which tells what datasets it was found in. I have my four datasets as dataframes, and the rownames are the IDs. Since I will be building up the final dataframe (calling it vectorTable) iteratively, I initialize it as an empty data frame. I have started working on a function which will do the folowing:

1. Check if an ID is in the vector table

   - If so update the correct boolean value
2. Otherwise build an new boolean vector and add it

Here is the code for the function:

```
mapIdToVector <- function(id, vectorTable, dataIdx) {

    if(id %in% vectorTable$id) {
        vectorTable[test$id == id][dataIdx] = TRUE
    } else {

        # create a vector for the row
        row <- c(id, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
        row[idx] = TRUE

        rbind(vectorTable, row)
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt at getting this to work, starting with just one dataset table.

```
idVectorization <- data.frame(id=character(), ds1=logical(), ds2=logical(), ds3=logical(), ds4=logical())

# two for ds1 since there is an id column
lapply(row.names(ds1), mapIdToVector, idVectorization, 2)
```

The issue is that the vectorTable is not getting updated. I don't know if it an issue with rbind() or with pass by reference / value. Any tips on how to get this to work would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it.

As you didn't provide data, here's some:

```
a <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:3])
b <- data.frame(ID = letters[3:6])
d <- data.frame(ID = letters[6:9])
e <- data.frame(ID = letters[9:12])
```

first, I'll combine your dataframes into a list and get out all the ids:

```
datlist <- list(a,b,d,e)
allids <- unique(unlist(sapply(datlist, function(x) as.character(x[["ID"]]))))
```

Then for each id, we check each data frame, using a nested sapply:

```
t(sapply(allids, function(x) sapply(datlist, function(y) x %in% y[["ID"]])))

   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
a  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
b  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
c  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
d FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
e FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
f FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
g FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
h FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
i FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
j FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
k FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
l FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```